# Determining what operation follows after SSH_FXP_OPEN message

Tags: sftp

In SFTP, SSH_FXP_OPEN request is initiated before writting/downloading file.

Is it possible to determine what request will follow? If its writting or downloading?

SSH_FXP_OPEN containts numerous flags, few of them seem like they could be the key factor to determine this however it seems many of them are unclear about this.

Is there any way how to determine what request will follow? I am talking about SFTP version 3+.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pflags` flag will typically contain one of `SSH_FXF_READ` and `SSH_FXF_WRITE`/`SSH_FXF_APPEND`. You can use that to guess what will follow.

But only *guess*, any request can follow. It's completely up to the client application. The application can open the file in both read AND write mode.

Also note that the client application can even have multiple files open in parallel, both for reading and writing.

Comment: well if he has multiple files opne, each file opens new "open" request right? I am missing the point of the last sentence

Comment: Yes it does, but I just wanted to make sure you understand that after OPEN (for file A), another OPEN can follow (for file B) and then a completely random mix of READ and WRITE requests for files A and B in any order. So basically, in general you have to expect *any* request at *any* time. Though it won't be common.

Comment: oh yes, but another READ or WRITE is identified by handle hash so its not that random. Still u answered my question, thanks!